# MediaPlayer - onCompletion issues

Tags: java, android

I have problem with onCompletion method for MediaPlayer.
Is there any way how to change sound while code running and play it?
I tried something like this:

```
    MediaPlayer player;

    public void play() {
        Database db = new Database(context);
            if (player == null) {
                player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zvuk);
                player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        stopPlayer();
                        db.open();
                        var = db.randomItem();
                        db.close();
                        play();
                        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zvuk2);
                        play();
                    }
                });
        }
        player.start();
    }

    public void stopPlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
                player.release();
                player = null;
        }
    }
```

But when I run this code, second soound will not work properly - sounds play over each other, when I pause player with my button, it will pause only "R.raw.zvuk", but second player still playing.
Do someone know solution for this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't have to create a new MediaPlayer each time but create just once and do "stop()" and then "setDataSource(..); start()".

Comment: I tried setDataSource too, but java wrote error. Can you please write code for me that will took sound from R.raw.zvuk2? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not 100% complete because the behaviour is:

1. you call play()
2. R.raw.zvuk is played
3. when R.raw.zvuk is completed then R.raw.zvuk2 is played
4. when R.raw.zvuk2 is completed then R.raw.zvuk2 is played again and again and again forever...
5. there isn't any way to stop this loop in this code

Code:

```
private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerrrrr";
@Nullable
private AssetFileDescriptor mLastAssetFileDescriptor = null;

public void play() {
    Database db = new Database(context);
    if (player == null) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zvuk);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(@NonNull final MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mLastAssetFileDescriptor != null) {
                    try { mLastAssetFileDescriptor.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) { /*nothing*/ }
                    mLastAssetFileDescriptor = null;
                }
                    //----------- I don't know what this part do --------
                db.open();
                var = db.randomItem();
                db.close();
                    //---------------------------------------------------
                mLastAssetFileDescriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.zvuk2);
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(mLastAssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), mLastAssetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), mLastAssetFileDescriptor.getLength());
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to set or play the new song: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (!player.isPlaying()) player.start();
    else Log.e(TAG, "MediaPlayer is already playing a song!!");
}
```

There are many better ways to do this kind of "infinite music player" but I preferred to not change your code too much to avoid to let you in confusion.

Comment: I got error, so your code doesnt work. And db.open() etc. is for database things

Comment: Is 95% Java and 5% pseudo-code, so you have to complete dependecies and/or fix mispelled words. I'm using a Mobile Phone and I cannot test the code, but it's 95% done.

Comment: You have written about: (1) willness to change sound while playing another one, (2) then you wanted to "took sound from zvuk2". You never asked for something different. We cannot completely change your code if what you were looking for was just few fixes. With my code you have (1) and (2) solved. If you want something different then look at my code and do according changes. If you have enough knowledge on Java it will be easy...and if not, then I suggest you to do more practice on it or be more clear on the request/question.